# comparing two list with different format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have two list :-

```
influx = [u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-2', 
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-1', 
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-7', 
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-10', 
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-9', 
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-4', 
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-3', 
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-8', 
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-6', 
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-5', 
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-11'] 

etcd =[u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-4', 
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-9', 
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-1', 
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-10', 
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-3', 
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-6', 
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-7', 
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-8', 
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-11', 
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-2', 
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-5']
```

Etcd is the parent list and I want to compare influx with Etcd.

1.) I want to get all elements which are not present in the list influx and return them.

2.) How I can convert the etcd list into influx list formatting by omitting `/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/`

Either of the above question will get me my solution.

I tried lots of methods but I am not getting my solution as they are in different format.

I will get my answer by doing `set(etcd)-set(influx)` but as they are in different format I am getting all the items in the list.

Comment: Why have you set tag pandas?

Comment: strip `/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/` part from `etcd`, then apply your set difference

Comment: Try `set([x.replace('/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/', '') for x in etcd])-set(influx)`

Comment: `[x for x in etcd if x.replace('/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/', '') not in influx]`

Answer (score 1):

#### `str.rsplit`

```
[x for x in etcd if x.rsplit('/', 1)[1] not in influx]
```

Per rafaelc's suggestion

```
infx = set(influx)
[x for x in etcd if x.rsplit('/', 1)[1] not in infx]
```

Comment: Good idea.  But you'd want to do it ahead of the comprehension to avoid creating the set every time. `infx = set(influx); [x for x in etcd if x.rsplit('/', 1)[1] not in infx]`

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to remove the prefixes

```py
for i, char in enumerate(etcd): 
    char = char.replace('/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/', '')
    etcd[i] = char
```

And then you could find the differences using `set()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
influx = [u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-2',
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-1',
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-7',
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-10',
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-9',
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-4',
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-3',
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-8',
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-6',
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-5',
          u'mphhos-fnwp-010101-11']

etcd =[u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-4',
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-9',
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-1',
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-10',
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-3',
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-6',
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-7',
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-8',
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-11',
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-2',
       u'/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/mphhos-fnwp-010101-5']

etcd = [x.replace('/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/', '') for x in etcd]

# or using regex
# etcd = [re.sub('/xymon/fnwp/mphhos/', '', x) for x in etcd]
diff = set(etcd) - set(influx)

print(diff)
```

Comment: Yes, like my comment!